# XSLT - template application

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

In a XSLT stylesheet I have defined the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@xlink:type = 'simple' and @xlink:href]">
    <a href="{@xlink:href}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="//mets:mets/mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp/mets:file/mets:FLocat">
    <a href="{@xlink:href}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:href"/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

In the XML-file the section "mets:mets/mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp/mets:file/mets:FLocat" is nested within "mets:mets/mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp/mets:file" and occurs several times.

When trying with only 2 sections of "mets:file" i use the following code to apply the template:

```
<tr bgcolor="#ff0000">
  <td>Filename</td>
  <td><xsl:apply-templates select="//mets:mets/mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp/mets:file/mets:FLocat" /></td>
</tr>
```

This should render a HTML-presentation as follows:

```
Data on file 1
.
.
.
Filename    file:///location/of/file1
Data on file 2
.
.
.
Filename    file:///location/of/file2
```

However what happens is this:

```
Data on file 1
.
.
.
Filename    file:///location/of/file1file:///location/of/file2
Data on file 2
.
.
.
Filename    file:///location/of/file1file:///location/of/file2
```

What am I doing wrong here?

/Paul

Comment: Post your full xslt, and your input xml

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. However I don't understand why?

The code above ....

```
<tr bgcolor="#ff0000">
  <td>Filename</td>
  <td><xsl:apply-templates select="//mets:mets/mets:fileSec/mets:fileGrp/mets:file/mets:FLocat" /></td>
</tr>
```

.... was changed to ....

```
<tr bgcolor="#ff0000">
  <td>Filename</td>
  <td><xsl:apply-templates select="." /></td>
</tr>
```

Then I got the desired output.

Could it be that the template gets all info it needs from this piece of code?

```
<xsl:template match="*[@xlink:type = 'simple' and @xlink:href]">
  <a href="{@xlink:href}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

/Paul